# How to fit a large amount of grid items inside of grid container without scrolling?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

I dynamically create grid items. When i create a large amount of grid items I would like them to get smaller and fit into container, instead of having overflow-y: scroll. How can  do this ?. I shared my code below :html, css. Would be very grateful if anybody can help me.

By default I divide my container into 4 col, but my goal is , when we creating a lot of items, I want them to fit into container and not create any scroll.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section {
  aspect-ratio: 5/2;
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 185, 185);
  margin: 0 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 2em;
  height: 100%;
}

.left,
.right {
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 185, 185);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.right {
    display: grid;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    align-content: flex-start;
}

.item-place {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;

}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>grid-css</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <button> Create grid item</button>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right">
                <!-- grid items will apear here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>




    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Basically you can't. CSS-Grid will keep creating columns unless you specify a number to stop at. You need JS for this.

Comment: By how much should the items shrink or what will be the minimum width and height of the items?